# Session getting lost after publishing (works on dev machine)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, telerik

I'm working on a Holiday Tracker application and one specific thing is killing the whole "page life cycle".

In my User Scheduler, where every user can insert his vacation, sometimes it's working (and  so he can insert/delete/edit and view his vacation).  There is also a Vacation page (same story there, just with a grid).

But sometimes the session that is set is getting lost. If I'm debugging with Visual Studio 2012, it's working.  But if I publish the application, it's not working.  It just gets lost somehow

Code in Global.asax.cs

```
    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Code that runs when a new session is started
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User is HtUser)
        {
            HtUser user = (HtUser)HttpContext.Current.User;
            Session["UserId"] = user.UserId;
            if(user.HtDepartments.Any() && user.HtDepartments.First().HtBusinessUnit != null){
                int BusinessUnitId  = user.HtDepartments.First().HtBusinessUnit.BusinessUnitId;
                Session["BusinessUnitId"] = BusinessUnitId;
            }

        }
    }
```

I think that maybe the error is there.

Scheduler:

```
<%--<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">--%>

        <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Unbooked vacation:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblBookedVacation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Lotus Notes" OnClientClick="Export(this, event); return false;" OnClick="btnExport_Click"></asp:Button>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;" />
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScheduler runat="server" ID="RadScheduler1" Width="750px" Height="700px"
                DayStartTime="07:00:00" DayEndTime="18:00:00" SelectedView="WeekView" DataSourceID="dsVactationDays"
                DataKeyField="VacationDayId" DataSubjectField="Title" DataStartField="FromDate" DataEndField="ToDate" OnAppointmentUpdate="RadScheduler1_AppointmentUpdate"
                OnAppointmentInsert="RadScheduler1_AppointmentInsert"
                OnRecurrenceExceptionCreated="RadScheduler1_RecurrenceExceptionCreated" OnTimeSlotCreated="RadScheduler1_TimeSlotCreated" OnAppointmentDataBound="RadScheduler1_AppointmentDataBound">
                <AdvancedForm Modal="true"></AdvancedForm>
                <TimelineView UserSelectable="false"></TimelineView>
                <TimeSlotContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true"></TimeSlotContextMenuSettings>
                <AppointmentContextMenuSettings EnableDefault="true"></AppointmentContextMenuSettings>
            </telerik:RadScheduler>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:DataGrid runat="server" DataSourceID="dsVactationDays" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:DataGrid>

        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsVactationDays" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=HolidayTrackerEntities" DefaultContainerName="HolidayTrackerEntities"
            EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="HtVacationDays"
            Where="it.UserId == @UserId">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter DbType="Int32" Name="UserId" SessionField="UserId" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:EntityDataSource>

    <%--</telerik:RadAjaxPanel>--%>
```

Code behind

```
   private const int AppointmentsLimit = 1;
       // private HtUser paramUser;
        private HtUser user;
        private HtUser User
        {
            get
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = HtUser.INIT_USER(this.Page, false);
                }
                return user;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack) {
                if (this.User != null) {
                    updateUnbookedVacationNotification();
                }
            }
            txtID.Text = Session["UserId"] != null ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "FUUUUU";
        }

        private void updateUnbookedVacationNotification() {
            double avAmount = User.GetAnnualVacationAmountByYear(this.RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.Year);
            double bookedAmount = User.GetBookedVacation(this.RadScheduler1.SelectedDate.Year);
            this.lblBookedVacation.Text = (avAmount - bookedAmount).ToString();
        }

        //private void getParameters()
        //{
        //    if (Page.Request["UserId"] != null)
        //    {
        //        int userId = Constants.TryConvert(Page.Request["userId"], this.Page);
        //        this.paramUser = HtUser.GetById(userId);
        //    }

        //}
        private bool ExceedsLimit(Appointment apt)
        {
            int appointmentsCount = 0;
            foreach (Appointment existingApt in RadScheduler1.Appointments.GetAppointmentsInRange(apt.Start, apt.End))
            {
                if (existingApt.Visible)
                    appointmentsCount++;
            }

            return (appointmentsCount > AppointmentsLimit - 1);
        }

        private bool AppointmentsOverlap(Appointment appointment)
        {
            if (ExceedsLimit(appointment))
            {
                foreach (Appointment a in RadScheduler1.Appointments.GetAppointmentsInRange(appointment.Start, appointment.End))
                {
                    if (a.ID != appointment.ID)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }



            return false;
        }

        private void RegisterScript()
        {
            Label1.Text = "Invalid move! There are appointments arranged for this time period.";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "LabelUpdated",
                    "$telerik.$('.lblError').show().animate({ opacity: 0.9 }, 2000).fadeOut('slow');", true);
        }


        protected void RadScheduler1_AppointmentInsert(object sender, SchedulerCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ExceedsLimit(e.Appointment))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                RegisterScript();
            }
            else
            {
                int id = HtUser.GetUserIdByLogin(Page.User.Identity.Name);
                e.Appointment.Attributes.Add("UserId", id.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Login Part
 Global.asax.cs

```
protected void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object source, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies.Get(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_COOKIE_NAME) != null)
                return;

            String strUserIdentity;
            FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthTicket;
            HttpCookie httpCook;
            String strEncryptedTicket;
            AdLookup adLookup = new AdLookup();

            strUserIdentity = e.Identity.Name;

            bool loggedIn = false;
            String email = null;
            String role = null;

            email = strUserIdentity; 
            HtUser userInfo = null;
            if (email != null && email != "")
            {
                userInfo = HtUser.GetByLogin(e.Identity, email);

                if (userInfo != null && userInfo.UserName.Length > 0)
                {
                    loggedIn = true;
                    role = HtUser.GetUserRoleString(userInfo);
                }
                //Checks if user is in domain
                else
                {
                    userInfo = adLookup.GetAdUserByUsername(HtUser.getUserNameFromDomainString(email));
                    if (userInfo != null && userInfo.UserName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        loggedIn = true;
                        role = UserRoles.User;
                    }
                }
            }
            //}

            if (loggedIn)
            {
                formsAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, email, DateTime.Now,
                                                                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), false, role);
                strEncryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(formsAuthTicket);
                httpCook = new HttpCookie(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_COOKIE_NAME, strEncryptedTicket);
                Response.Cookies.Add(httpCook);
                HttpContext.Current.User = userInfo;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ch-s-0008086;Initial Catalog=HolidayTracker;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123.;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HolidayTrackerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ch-s-0008086;Initial Catalog=HolidayTracker;User ID=sa;Password=123." providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HolidayTrackerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.HolidayTracker.csdl|res://*/Model.HolidayTracker.ssdl|res://*/Model.HolidayTracker.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ch-s-0008086;Initial Catalog=HolidayTracker;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123.;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="HolidayTrackerEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.HTTracker.csdl|res://*/DAL.HTTracker.ssdl|res://*/DAL.HTTracker.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ch-s-0008086;initial catalog=HolidayTracker;user id=sa;password=123.;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LDAP_SERVER_NAME" value="asdasdasd" />
    <add key="LDAP_USERNAME" value="asdasdas" />
    <add key="LDAP_PASSWORD" value="asdasdasd" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
      <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" /></httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="RadUploadModule" />

      <remove name="RadCompression" /><add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" /></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
      <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
      <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

If you need something more, just let me know.

Comment: Have you noticed any pattern to when the "session gets lost"?  How often it happens?  Also, how do you know that the session gets lost (what is the reported symptom)?

Comment: how you can see in my scheduler i have created a TextBox and if   txtID.Text = Session["UserId"] != null ? Session["UserId"].ToString() : "FUUUUU"; so i know that its lost

Comment: Do you have some application pool auto-recycling ? Is it Forms authentication ? Could you post relevant web.config parts for session management and authentication management ?

Comment: Mingebag - you need to use "@" notifications to respond to people (so that they get notified).  @jbl won't have seen your reply.

Comment: @Mingebag are these real username and password ?!

Comment: ok LDAP ones seemed quite complex for fakes ;-) Don't see the sessionstate element in your web.config, assuming default values. You seem to be using some Forms Authent mechanism, but Authent in config seems to be windows. I must confess I'm lost

Comment: @jbl haha ;)np but can you help me to find a solution how would you  do it post it as a answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InProc session storage and publish your application, the application pool gets recycled by the IIS and the w3wp.exe process respawns. Your session data is then lost immediately.

If that is the problem you're having, and you want to avoid it, there are options for storing your session elsewhere (such as in a database).  See the MSDN article on [ASP.NET Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I don't know for sure that this is the OPs problem, but it is certainly a good observation, and a distinct possibility.  +1 from me.

Comment: PS: I edited you answer to add a link to some options for session management.  I hope you don't mind =)

Comment: @Peit can you plzz delete your answer i want to close this thread i got the solution by my self

Comment: @Mingebag Why not share your solution here?

Comment: @ThomasS the "solution" is that i created everything new so lite bit to much .. to be honest its not a real solution cause i don't know where the error was

Comment: No I won't delete it because we've discovered exactly the same problem you described first and my and jadarnel27's answer might help other people with similar problems. Feel free to create an answer by yourself and mark it as solution. :-)

Concerning the downvote, see: "When should I vote down? Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." I'm pretty sure this is not the case here.

Comment: @Minebag That's propably right but it could have been a valid solution for your problem. Just providing not the accepted solution is no reason for a downvote in my opinion. Anyway, I'm happy you found a solution for your concern.

Comment: @Peit if you need the reputation np I can give you a up vote ...?

Comment: @Mingebag :-) No it's ok, I will gather my reputation points regularly. Thanks anyway.